# change the box account or copying structure with the same IDs

Tags: box-api

I have multiple environments for dev and qa, I want to copy the files from one account to another or MOVE them but to use the same exact IDs or to copy and get a list of the new IDs to update my records.

Any idea how or if there is any script?

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to change the email of my account, in the enterprise accounts you can change it from Users, so the admin can change but the user can't.